How to find a network bottleneck
I'm currently unable to find where, in my application, the bottleneck is located. The issue isn't hardware specific as I made tests on different computers using different hardware.
My application is developed using Qt 5.15 and C++ language, for Windows 10 or higher only.
The goal of the application is to connect, through an HTTP network connection, to a server (another application) which handles a datamodel of a controlled machine. The datamodel is a list of parameter representing the state of the machine. The server also allows retrieving some "heavier" data like images to be displayed for the user.
The "Client" application uses the HTTP protocol and the PUT HTTP's method to send messages and read-back answers from the server. As I use Qt's libraries, I base my connection on QNetworkRequest, QNetworkReply and QNetworkAccessManager classes to perform network operations.
The client application works with an autopoll (100ms minimum between 2 poll) to have updates from the server. The autopoll just PUT a "GetUpdate" request: following, the exact data sent to the server to request a simple update of the datamodel.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Request requestType="GetUpdated"/>

If the server handled update of a machine's parameter, the answer to this request will contain the specific parameter with the new value.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<Response responseType="GetUpdated"> 
  <Device Name="ServerCore" type="0"> 
    <Parameter Name="DateTime" type="String"> 
      <Actual>2024-10-09T15:42:52</Actual> 
    </Parameter> 
  </Device> 
</Response> 

Above, there is an example of update answer. The data size may vary depending on the quantity of parameter updated. But I based all my performance analysis on this kind of data size.
The issue
When a request is going to be sent to the server application, I create a QElapsedTimer to estimate the elapsed time between the request sent and the handled reply from the server.
The issue is that when I use a "Private Network" architecture between the server and the client, the elapsed time is too high for my kind of application. Even if my network handles switches/rooter/etc.. The elapsed time is similar to the simplest network: a cable directly connected from the server to the client. ~50ms maximum
If I run a server and a client on the same computer (using 127.0.0.1), the elapsed time is more acceptable. ~3ms maximum

Private Network architecture
Local Network architecture

To be sure the Data Link & Physical Layer was the real bottleneck, I create a standalone python application to connect to the server and make the same processes as my client's. My python application is more efficient than My Qt's one on private networks (~5ms maximum) for the same requests. My python application uses http.client library (https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html)
So I conclude that Qt was the problem, but why can I have equivalent delay on local network I don't know if it's really Qt's fault.
Improvement tests
To reduce the Qt delay, I tried to:

use the Synchronous method of QNetworkReply class: waitForReadyRead (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#waitForReadyRead)
Create a Specific QThread for the communication process.
Add Priority level to requests (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkrequest.html#setPriority)

But none of them reduced the delay. I don't know if it's really the Qt's fault.
If it's the NIC's fault, why is my Python application can improve performances ?

I sniffed the connection with WireShark to quantify the network transfer time. I ran wireshark on both computer and match the corresponding packet to determine the transmission time.
The result is:

Client to Server took: ~0.21ms
Server To Client too: ~0.22ms
Total took: ~0.43ms

My question about these new information is: Which layer WireShark is sniffing?

What speed is your LAN?  100MB/s?  1GB/s?  What about the NICs on your machines?

From what I understand, the problem isn't the network. Your Wireshark logs show the network connections are actually very fast and your standalone python is comparatively quick as well (you could also directly curl instead). How about performance profiling your client application, e.g., with CProfile?

My LAN is 1Gb/s with RJ45 CAT6, with the Wiresharks logs I'm sure that the physical layer isn't the bottleneck.
I will try to develop a custom network access manager using curl library, to compare with the Qt's solution. Thank you

I had answer from the Qt support team about this problem, and it's a Qt5's problem. They opened a bug report about this kind of issue.
Moving the code from Qt5 to Qt6 improved the performance and allows having an answer with a ~5ms delay, which is more acceptable for our kind of application.
Edit:
Qt's bug report: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-130438

Please [edit] this answer to add a link to the bug report in case it helps future readers.
